# How to structure a Client–Server data Model solution?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, client-server

I need to write a client–server solution. The server will perform scheduled operations and also serve up data from a SQL DB to the client.

The client is yet to be fully defined but it will make requsts to the server and display data for the user and pass data back for persistence.

The whole solution is dealing with entities (Users, Products, etc. with their associated attributes).

In my head, both the server and the client need to be aware of these entities in order for them to be efficiently manipulated in code rather than having to unpack JSON and duplicate code.

My question is, should I make a class library containing models (classes or structs) representing these entities that is referenced by both the client- and server-side projects?

Otherwise, is there some standard way of building such a solution?

Thus far I have a client, a server (based on ASP.NET 2) and a Class Library containing entity Models along with some data access logic. Both the client and server projects reference the Class Library. One day in and I’m already starting to doubt my approach as being too clumsy.

I will be working with VS2019 using C#.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a question well suited to StackOverflow which aims to solve specific code/tech problems.

It is possible to use the same model (Entity) in both client and server, but I highly recommend separating the client model (view model) from the domain model. (Entity) The reasons for this are:

- Clients rarely need, or should expose every domain field & relationship. Sending models from server to client involve serialization. This can result in either performance issues or errors as the serializer "touches" properties and wants to lazy-load them, or you add the cost of eager-loading everything; Or it results in incomplete models where unloaded relationships are left null. (Not because there aren't any, they just weren't loaded)  Client models should be trimmed down to just the data the client needs to see, formatted in a way it can use. Ultimately this is shipping more data than needed to the client and back. Keep the payloads over the wire as small as possible.
- Security can be an issue when passing entities from Client to Server. Your UI may only allow users to change a few values in a very particular way, but the temptation can be to take that entity, attach it to a DB Context and update it. (1 line updates) However, this entity sent from the client can very easily be tampered with by the browser which can result in changes being made that you don't expect/allow. (I.e. change a FK relationship)
  At best this can allow stale data overwrites where changes made after that record was sent to the client are overwritten silently when the client gets around to submitting their change. Don't trust data coming from a client, especially under the premise of "saving time". Update requests should validate the data coming in and re-load the Entity to check things like the row version before updating allowed values.

Enabling view models can be done using a technique supported in EF called Projection. This can either be hand-written using `.Select` or leveraging tools like Automapper and its `ProjectTo` method to easily transform entities and Linq expressions into simple, dumb serializable view models. When a view model comes back to the server, you simply load an entity and associations from the DB by ID, and update values after validation steps and `SaveChanges` to persist.